# Starting SonarQube 4.5 fails on SLES 11 SP2

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to start SonarQube 4.5 on SLES 11 SP2 but it fails to start.

I'm getting the following output, so I guess the problem is with the Web Server.

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2014.12.10 11:14:55 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /usr/lib64/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/bin/java -Xmx256m -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/etc/sonarqube/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process8084089595852251307properties
jvm 1    | 2014.12.10 11:15:04 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
jvm 1    | 2014.12.10 11:15:04 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib64/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/bin/java -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djava.io.tmpdir=/etc/sonarqube/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/etc/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /tmp/sq-process8998624016648577337properties
jvm 1    | 2014.12.10 11:15:21 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopping
jvm 1    | 2014.12.10 11:15:22 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

The installed Java version is:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Hope someone can help me,

Stefan

edit:
the sonar.log file contains the following:
[sonar.log](http://textuploader.com/oib2) due to character limitations I had to upload them to a different site

changed sonar properties; removed link to mysql, so sonar will use (for test purposes) the internal db.
It still fails to start, log can be found here [sonar.log](http://textuploader.com/oib8)

Comment: Can you please update your question to add the content of the "logs/sonar.log" file please? Otherwise we can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `ConnectException: Connection refused` error in your log, so you might want to check that:

- Your MySQL server is started
- Your JDBC configuration is correct (e.g connecting with the `mysql` command line utility to check credentials)
- The MySQL port (3306) is open (no firewall)

[EDIT]

Then you get a `java.net.UnknownHostException: Linux-Schulung` which seems to indicate a name resolution failure. Please check that your DNS settings and/or `/etc/hosts` are correct

Comment: There was indeed a problem with the DB so I modified the settings so that Sonar will now use the internal DB until the DB-issue is fixed. Nevertheless the problem that Sonar won't start persists. I added a second log file to my original post.

Comment: Thank you for your time and information. There was a wrong nameserver configured. Now Sonar is up and running.